# Erro no ionic 3

Tags: ionic, ionic3

Baixei as ferramentas para a utilização do framework **ionic cordova**

> Java Baixei o java jdk1.8.0_171
>
> apache-ant-1.10.4
>
> android-sdk

Configurei as variáveis de ambiente

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dou enter na linha **ionic cordova build android** e aparece o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pelo que pesquisei as variáveis estão corretas..

Answer (score 0):

instale o https://gradle.org/install/ no caminho C:\Gradle basta extrair o zip nessa pasta.

Depois edite o `GRADLE_HOME` para `C:\Gradle\gradle-4.0.1`

E o `PATH` para `C:\Gradle\gradle-4.0.1\bin`